# How musl library malloc() implementation decided bin index?

Tags: linux

In musl library malloc() implementation MMAP_THRESHOLD value is 229376 Bytes and accordingly bin_index (index used to find free blocks stored in "mal.bins" for later requests) is range from 0 to 63. And i want to increase the MMAP_THRESHOLD to 1GB, do  i need to increase the range for bin_index ... ?

Comment: @Ivan sir can you explain this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have studied the musl library malloc() implementation. According two my understanding bin index is calculated as log to the base 2 of size. i.e exponent part when size is represented with power of 2.

Below is the code snippet of function  bin_index() function.

```
static int bin_index(size_t x)
{
    x = x / SIZE_ALIGN - 1;
    if (x <= 32) return x;
    if (x > 0x1c00) return 63;
    return ((union { float v; uint32_t r; }){(int)x}.r>>21) - 496;
}
```

In the above function while calculating the bin index first size is divided by 32 to calculate x and if x value is less than or equal to 32, then bin[0] to bin[32] are used. But if x is greater than 32 then index is calculated by converting x into 32 bit (**IEEE 754 standard**) floating point representation. In 32 bit representation 1 bit used as **sign bit**, 8 bit are used for **exponent** and 23 bit are used for **mantissa**. If you see in above code, x value is right shifted by 21 instead of 23 (Two extra bit from mantissa part are used) to find the exponent. The reason behind this is to convert two logarithmic point into four steps (linearly) and then bias 496 is subtracted to get the exponent (bin index).

why 496...? 
when we used two extra bits from mantissa part then exponent will be 10 bit. So bias value for 10 bit exponent will be -512 (for negative numbers) and 511 (for positive numbers). i.e maximum number that can be represented with 10 bits. In this case bias will be 511 as all values will be positive. Then 15 (index offset) is subtracted from 511 to adjust the bin index from 32 to 63. 511 - 15 = 496

The bin index are used with four linear steps between to logarithmic points when MMAP_THRESHOLD value is 229376 Bytes. But if we increase the MMAP_THRESHOLD to 1GB same bin index from 0 to 63 can be used with little modification in bin_index(). You should represent the number with 64 bit floating point representation instead of 32 bit and there is no need to used bin index with four linear steps between two logarithmic point as follow

```
 static int bin_index(size_t x)
    {
        x = x / SIZE_ALIGN - 1;
        if (x <= 32) return x;
        if (x > 0x2000000) return 63;
        return ((union { double v; uint64_t r; }){(int64_t)x}.r>>52) - 996;
    }
```